# How to use hybrid source using python client in apache flink?

Tags: python, apache-flink

I have a use case where i have to joins the historical data with the realtime data, I want  to use the Hybrid Source which uses the csv file that store historical aggregate data and want to join the same with realtime aggregate data, I can't find example doing the same. I want to do this using python client of the apache flink with latest version v1.17.dev. Any lead is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Support for the HybridSource has been added to pyflink for the 1.16 release (which will be released very soon). The [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/python/pyflink.datastream.html#module-pyflink.datastream.connectors.hybrid_source) includes this example:

```py
file_source = FileSource
     .for_record_stream_format(StreamFormat.text_line_format(), test_dir)
     .build()
kafka_source = KafkaSource
    .builder()
    .set_bootstrap_servers('localhost:9092')
    .set_group_id('MY_GROUP')
    .set_topics('quickstart-events')
    .set_value_only_deserializer(SimpleStringSchema())
    .set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.earliest())
    .build()
hybrid_source = 
    HybridSource.builder(file_source).add_source(kafka_source).build()
```